# Skewed residuals from log-linear model

Tags: predictive-models, residuals

This is a residuals plot of $y_{pred}$ - $y_{true}$ and $log(y_{true} + 1)$. I'm under-predicting the higher values of $log(y_{true} + 1)$.

Has someone seen this pattern before with a log-linear model? I'm thinking I'm missing an independent variable, but not quite sure exactly how to correct the issue. Any guidance would be appreciated.

The model I built is trying to predict the revenue from a customer. Revenue is bound between 0 and 230, but highly skewed to 0 - hence log-linear. My dataset is very large, roughly 1MM observations and I have roughly 12 independent variables, mixed between continuous and categorical.

[image]

Comment: You appear to be plotting the *negative* of the residuals vs a monotonic increasing transformation of the response, which will necessarily have a negative relationship. Many posts on site deal with the fact that residuals will be positively related to the response (across all manner of models). Plot against the fit not the dependent variable itself.